# Angular best way to watch two form fields

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of persons, each one should have phone and name,
so I did :

```
<div ng-repeat="a in arr">
  <ng-form>
    phone{{a}}:<input type="phone" name="phone" />
    text{{a}}:<input type="text" name="name" />
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

When finish to enter phone and name for the first person, I want to call "doSomething" function .

What is the best way to do that? I prefer to not use watch.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BrPuSxT9YCdiVOdfMS6v?p=preview) for example.

Comment: @i would suggest you to call function on form submit instead of watching fields

Comment: but I have many other fields on my form, and I want to know when these two are complete, even if the other are not

Comment: dont watch... add ng-change only on those two fields... and in that function check if both are defined and do your stuff

Comment: You can make these two fields as required and check if form is valid on blur of any field of these two. In this case you do not need to make if else condition for blank fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [`ng-blur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) in your case. Using [`ng-keyup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) will trigger the function on every key release event, which is not good at all. You should check below example example how it works

```
 phone{{a}}:<input type="phone" data-ng-blur="doSomething();" name="phone" />
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/7VzuegRblu3MzzPnzk1V?p=preview) to check more.

**EDIT**

If you only want to execute for the first iteration then you should pass `index` to your function and check if its equals to `0`. Then it must be for first iteration. like

```
ng-blur="doSomething($index)"
```

In your function

```
$scope.doSomething = function(index){
if(index === 0)
   alert("finish");
};
```

Comment: This works, but I want the ng-blur to be just for the first person, now the alert happens for all persons

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways to achieve this is

```
 <input type="phone" name="phone" ng-model="input.phone"  ng-change="onchange()"/>
 <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="input.name" ng-change="onchange()"//>
```

and then on your scope

```
 scope.input = {};
 scope.onchange = function(){
       if(!input.phone) return;
       if(!input.name) return;
       //other logic
 }
```

btw, best practises says always have a dot in your ng-model

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you're looking for the following.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="a in arr">
  <ng-form>
    phone{{a}}:<input type="phone" name="phone" ng-change="doSomething()" />
    text{{a}}:<input type="text" name="name" ng-change="doSomething()"/>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.doSomething= function () {
// do something
};
```

**Note:** You can also use `ng-blur` that will be triggered only once you leave focus from input field.